# calculate cubic equation from two points and two slopes, variably

Tags: polynomials, cubics, bezier-curve

I'm trying to variably calculate the cubic equation between two points and the slopes at said points. *(Ultimately to get an approximation of a bezier spline where i can calculate the y value from a given x value)*

I have two 2-dimensional points, $(x0,y0)$ and $(x1,y1)$. They both have a slope value, lets call them $m0$ and $m1$.

From this i tried to derivate 4 linear simultaneous equations, using the basic cubic equation as well as the first derivation like this:

$y0=a*x0^3+b*x0^2+c*x0+d$
$y1=a*x1^3+b*x1^2+c*x1+d$
$m0=3*a*x0^2+2*b*x0+c$
$m1=3*a*x1^2+2*b*x1+c$

Since i have control over the points and can move $x0$ to $0$, the equations are relatively easy to solve (or so I thought):

$y0=d$ and $m0=c$. If I use these to solve for $a$ and $b$ i get

$a=(2/x1^2)*( (m0-m1)/2)+ (y0-y1)/x2)$
$b=(m0-m1)/(-2*x1) - (3*a*x1)/2$

using those to individually calculate $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ from any given pair of points (including slopes) should give me the optimal curve, but it only works for $m1=0$. All the other values I can change and get the expected results (except for $x0$ which was established as the fix $0$).

If it helps, I will gladly provide my step-by-step way how i got to those numbers, but for now I'm kinda stomped at where i went wrong.

[Link to Desmos Graphing Calculator for Visualisation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/54wbqkugfa)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is "variably" ?

Comment: Are you after an explicit relation $y=B(x)$, which describes a function, or a planar curve described by parametric equations $x=B_x(t),y=B_y(t)$ ?

Comment: I used "variably" to indicate that i'm not after concrete numbers and more after an algorithm to solve for any number i add in. And I'm after the explicit relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions are

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 a x_0^3+b x_0^2+c x_0+d=y_0 \\
 a x_1^3+b x_1^2+c x_1+d=y_1 \\
 3 a x_0^2+2 b x_0+c=m_0 \\
 3 a x_1^2+2 b x_1+c=m_1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving this linear system we obtain the values $a,b,c,d$

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
a&=& \frac{\left(m_0+m_1\right) \left(x_0-x_1\right)-2 y_0+2 y_1}{\left(x_0-x_1\right){}^3} \\
b&=& \frac{-m_0 \left(x_0-x_1\right) \left(x_0+2 x_1\right)+m_1 \left(-2 x_0^2+x_1 x_0+x_1^2\right)+3 \left(x_0+x_1\right)
   \left(y_0-y_1\right)}{\left(x_0-x_1\right){}^3} \\
c&=& \frac{m_1 x_0 \left(x_0-x_1\right) \left(x_0+2 x_1\right)-x_1 \left(m_0 \left(-2 x_0^2+x_1 x_0+x_1^2\right)+6 x_0
   \left(y_0-y_1\right)\right)}{\left(x_0-x_1\right){}^3} \\
d&=& \frac{\left(x_0-3 x_1\right) y_1 x_0^2+x_1 \left(x_0 \left(x_1-x_0\right) \left(m_1 x_0+m_0 x_1\right)-x_1 \left(x_1-3 x_0\right)
   y_0\right)}{\left(x_0-x_1\right){}^3} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: thank you. this allowed me to check my previous solutions using x0 = 0 and thus i could confirm that my solutions were in fact correct and my problem was at a different point.